# Accessing a function through z3py that's already been defined

Tags: z3, z3py

Does anybody please know if there's a way to interact with a function through z3py that I've already defined in Z3 and parsed using parse_smt2_string ? I'm a Z3 and python and Z3Py newbie so apologies if this is obvious, but I've not found any similar questions on here so far...

I've tried things of the form:

```html
original = """ 
(define-fun MyFun () Real 
....
)
"""

f = parse_smt2_string (original) 
s = Solver() 
s.add(f) 
MyFun = Function('MyFun')
s.push()
s.add(MyFun <= 0.4)
s.check()
s.pop()

s.push()
s.add(MyFun >= 0.8)
s.check()
s.pop()
```

But this returns different results to if I add the assertions into the Z3 string I'm parsing. I think it's because it's not recognising that MyFun in python is the same as in the string. So presumably, I'm defining the function incorrectly, but I can't work out what I'm doing wrong. I've also tried `MyFun = Function('MyFun', RealSort())` but that didn't work....

Can anyone help me out please? :)

Comment: At the minute, I'm asserting a constant equal to the function result in the parsed code, and then asserting things about the constant in z3py..... maybe a bit messy, but looks to be working so far...